# How do I publish pact contracts on build for .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, pact, pact-broker

Apparently this is possible for Java apps with Gradle.

I don't want to have to run some separate script for publishing my pact contract for my .net core apps.

How do I publish my pact contract during `dotnet build`?

This might be outside the scope of my question but can I publish contracts to s3 this way too?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently supported as you say. Perhaps raise an issue requesting how you'd like to see it integrated with your particular build tool of choice? For example, with gradle it is common to have various tasks such as `publish` that are executed separately to the build. Having it done as part of a build sounds unusual to me.

But raising a feature request is a good starting point, also making the case as to why a separate script is inferior.

FWIW I rarely use such features, publishing is usually only performed in CI as a distinct build step anyway and is a trivial task to automate.